# PN532 (SPI) how to get firmware version

Tags: stm32, rfid, nfc

I am trying to use PN532 for Mifare card reading on STM32F4.
Before even trying to go forward I have tried to read firmware version to verify that all works ok and cannot do it.

I am trying to base off [NFC READER V3](http://www.elechouse.com/elechouse/images/product/PN532_module_V3/PN532_%20Manual_V3.pdf) and [ELEC code](https://github.com/elechouse/PN532).

My code looks like:

```
  uint32_t versiondata;
  uint32_t chip_version;
  uint32_t fw_version_maj;
  uint32_t fw_version_min;


  PN532_SPI__wakeup(&dd_PN532__reader);

  versiondata = PN532__getFirmwareVersion(&dd_PN532__reader);

  chip_version = (versiondata>>24) & 0xFF;
  fw_version_maj = (versiondata>>16) & 0xFF;
  fw_version_min = (versiondata>>8) & 0xFF;
```

I have ported it to be C not C++ as in original.

Code fails at:

```
uint32_t PN532__getFirmwareVersion(devicedriver_PN532 *dd)
{
    uint32_t response;

    dd->pn532_packetbuffer[0] = PN532_COMMAND_GETFIRMWAREVERSION;

    if (PN532_SPI__writeCommand(dd,dd->pn532_packetbuffer, 1, 0, 0)) {
 ------- FAILS ------> return 0;
    }

    // read data packet
    int16_t status = PN532_SPI__readResponse(dd,dd->pn532_packetbuffer, sizeof(dd->pn532_packetbuffer),1000);
    if (0 > status) {
        return 0;
    }

    response = dd->pn532_packetbuffer[0];
    response <<= 8;
    response |= dd->pn532_packetbuffer[1];
    response <<= 8;
    response |= dd->pn532_packetbuffer[2];
    response <<= 8;
    response |= dd->pn532_packetbuffer[3];

    return response;
}
```

Callstack for reference:

```
int8_t PN532_SPI__writeCommand(devicedriver_PN532 *dd, const uint8_t *header, uint8_t hlen, const uint8_t *body, uint8_t blen)
{
    dd->command = header[0];
    PN532_SPI__writeFrame(dd,header, hlen, body, blen);

    uint8_t timeout = PN532_ACK_WAIT_TIME;
    while (!PN532_SPI__isReady(dd)) {
        dd->delay(1);
        timeout--;
        if (0 == timeout) {
            //DMSG("Time out when waiting for ACK\n");
            return -2;
        }
    }
    if (PN532_SPI__readAckFrame(dd)) {
        //DMSG("Invalid ACK\n");
        return PN532_INVALID_ACK;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which seems to fails at comparing:

```
int8_t PN532_SPI__readAckFrame(devicedriver_PN532 *dd)
{
    const uint8_t PN532_ACK[] = {0, 0, 0xFF, 0, 0xFF, 0};

    uint8_t ackBuf[sizeof(PN532_ACK)];

    dd->spi_cs_low();
    dd->delay(10);
    dd->spi_write(DATA_READ);

    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < sizeof(PN532_ACK); i++) {
        ackBuf[i] = dd->spi_read();
    }

    dd->spi_cs_high();

    return memcmp(ackBuf, PN532_ACK, sizeof(PN532_ACK));
}
```

[image]

Output from logic analyzer gives:

```
Time [s],Packet ID,MOSI,MISO
0.001900600000000,0,0x02,0x01
0.001916100000000,0,0x00,0x01
0.012942050000000,1,0x01,0x01
0.012957400000000,1,0x00,0xFF
0.012972500000000,1,0x00,0xFF
0.012987550000000,1,0xFF,0xFF
0.013002650000000,1,0x02,0xFF
0.013017750000000,1,0xFE,0xFF
0.013032800000000,1,0xD4,0xFF
0.013048050000000,1,0x02,0xFF
0.013063450000000,1,0x2A,0xFF
0.013078500000000,1,0x00,0xFF
0.013094650000000,2,0x02,0xFF
0.013109750000000,2,0x00,0x01
0.014950450000000,3,0x02,0x01
0.014965800000000,3,0x00,0x00
0.025992800000000,,0x03,0x00
0.026008250000000,,0x00,0x00
0.026023400000000,,0x00,0x6E
0.026038600000000,,0x00,0xCB
0.026053800000000,,0x00,0xBB
0.026068950000000,,0x00,0x6F
0.026084150000000,,0x00,0x4F
```

Any hints? Is hardware failing...

If possible could anyone share their logic analyzer output for getting firmware version so I can compare it?

TNX.

Comment: I did not look through your code, but in _working_ Adafruit library for this board they call GetFirmwareVersion and discard result once on startup. The comment in code says: "not exactly sure why but we have to send a dummy command to get synced up".

Comment: Tnx for the hint... had a look at it.... added the same thing but no change.Also took another new unpacked module just to check that no HW issue is hidden in this mess but result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

want to share solution...

...being affected by "silicon limitations" (we all know what that means...) It seems that following proposed solution it worked.

This is quote from [community.st.com][1]

> Problem resolved (underlined the workaround). STM32F40x and STM32F41x
>   silicon limitations, section 2.4.13:
>
> LSB bit of data or CRC calculation can be corrupted for the
>   receiveddata in master mode depending on the timing of the
>   feedbackcommunication clock respect to the APB clock (SPI or I2S)
>   Description
>
> When the SPI or I2S is configured in master mode (in full duplex or
>   receiver mode, readingback the data register or CRC enabled), the data
>   received may have the last transacted bitcorrupted if delay of
>   internal feedback derived from SCK pin is comparable with APB
>   clockperiod. The last bit value is strobed too late into the shift
>   register, while its content has beenalready either copied into the
>   data register or compared with CRC pattern calculatedinternally. In
>   case of data corruption, the bit position in the data register
>   contains the value ofthe last bit received during the previous data
>   transfer and CRCERR flag is asserted in spiteof all the data being
>   received correctly.
>
> The main factors which can contribute negatively to the delay are
>   decreased Vdd level,extreme temperature, high SPI bus capacity load
>   and low SCK IO output speed. SPIcommunication speed has no impact.
>
> Workaround
>
> â€¢ Decrease the APB clock.
>
> â€¢ Set the IO pad configuration for the SCK pin to be faster.
>
> â€¢ Ignore the lastly transacted bit value
>
> [1]:
>   https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009XkfHYSAZ/possible-hardware-bug-full-duplex-spi-incorrectly-reads-last-bit-of-each-incoming-byte

Comment: Please "accept" your self-answer so that the question shows as resolved